# Matrix Visualization with multiple colors and shades

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, grid, visualization

I have a huge matrix.  I'm talking 4^7x4^7.  Each grid cell has a probability distribution associated with it.  I would like to visualize this matrix by assigning a color to it based on the highest probability and a shade based on the magnitude of the probability.  For example:

```
__                                         __
|(.8,.1,.1) (.6,.3,.1) (.4,.4,.2) (.2,.6,.2)|
|(.1,.6,.3) (.1,.2,.7) (.2,.3,.5) (.1,.4,.5)|
|(.4,.1,.5) (.3,.1,.6) (.6,.2,.2) (.7,.1,.2)|
|(.2,.5,.3) (.8,.1,.1) (.4,.3,.3) (.2,.6,.2)|
__                                         __
```

I would want cells (1,1), (1,2), (3,3), (3,4), (4,2), (4,3) to be red, with cell (1,1) being a darker shade than (4,3)
Also, I would want (1,4), (2,1), (4,1), (4,4) to be blue, with (1,4) being darker than (4,1)
And so on and so forth.

My actual implementation will need 8 separate colors.  I was planning on doing this in Matlab, but if it would be easier in Excel I can use that.

Any ideas? Is this too crazy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your probability matrix `P` is of size `m`-by-`n`-by-`k` with `k` the number of classes/colors you have.
In that case you can do:

```
>> colors = rand( k, 3 ); % pick k differet colors
>> [shade idx] = max( P, [], 3 ); % choose class per pixel
>> output = ind2rgb( idx, colors ); % convert class to colors
>> output = bsxfun( @times, output, shade ); % apply the shade
>> figure; imshow( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Colors and matrix, that sounds like heat map. Here's an example built in d3js:

http://vida.io/documents/6NHboDKAAei9r5j2S

Looks like you can also do heat map in Matlab.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24253-customizable-heat-maps/content/html/heatmap_examples.html

Comment: please try not to post link-only answers.

Comment: Shai, my answer isn't link only. The main point is to use heat map visualization, first sentence. I think it's a nice way to visualize the given dataset. The links include demos/pictures that can explain better than words.